# In 2019, do any OSS/IBIS implementations offer some degree of subject tracking?

Tags: image-stabilization

Theoretically, an IBIS or OSS system could be used to reduce motion blur for a reasonably slow moving subject (think aircraft or vehicles in low light) when very fast shutter speeds are not viable. Subject tracking algorithms exist in the market, but are used for autofocus. The information they deliver would appear to be usable to follow a subject across a fraction of the frame using the stabilizer mechanism.

Is there any maker already implementing this, apart from Pentax' GPS-based (specialized) astrotracking features that have been around for a while?

Comment: What about some sort of gimbal with object tracking?

Comment: @vclaw that would certainly help increase the exposure duration and/or tracking range (travel distance of subject), allowing for at least somewhat faster moving subjects. But gimbal tracking won't be able to be nearly as precise as either OSS or IBIS in accurately following the subject. That is, the closed loop tracking is faster and more precise when the loop is smaller, and the controller has to deal with orders of magnitude less inertia. I'd love to see a combined IBIS+gimbal system for cameras, at a prosumer price point.

Comment: AFAIK you can't use the sensor data while you're taking an image. Stabilization systems use gyroscopic sensors.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not in the way that you are asking.

But there are some camera bodies with IBIS that use the ability of the sensor to move to track the sky in moderately long exposures of the night sky. Rather than starting in the center of the sensor's range of travel, they start on one edge and move until they reach the limits of movement on the other edge. This helps counteract the earth's rotation beneath the night sky. The cameras still needs to be supported on a solid mount, though, because the motion of the sensor is computed by the camera based on lens focal length and other parameters and does not compensate for irregular camera movement, only for the calculated movement of the earth beneath the sky during exposure.

Comment: Sounds like the Pentax system?

Comment: @rackandboneman Are you talking about the [Astrotracer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/104866/11924) system?

Comment: @rackandboneman Among others, some Pentax cameras include such a feature.